# How to use an index as a column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have a Dataframe in panda with an index = Country names

i want to create a column continent

```
DF['Continent'] = DF['Country'].apply(lambda x: ContinentDict[x])
```

but i can't as country is an index. is there a similar solution?

all i do for now is something like this:

```
DF['Continent']= Top15.index #gets the country name
DF['Continent']= DF['Continent'].apply(lambda x: ContinentDict[x])
```

but i feel it's ugly

Edit:

I also tried

```
Top15['Continent']=[ContinentDict[x] for x in Top15.index]
```

but i feel it's really nasty also

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the index for the purpose of the transformation:

```
DF.reset_index()['Country'].apply(lambda x: ContinentDict[x])
```

The cleanest approach, however, is to use the `.replace` method:

```
DF.reset_index()['Country'].replace(ContinentDict)
```

Comment: Thanks, why is it replace? for perf?

Comment: `apply/lambda` is not a pandas operation and often leads to inferior performance.